# Can't seem to scrape specific information from webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to scrape some information for each item displayed on the following page:
https://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CatalogSearchResultView?storeId=10051&catalogId=10051&langId=-1&categoryId=1351370&variety=New+Spirits&categoryType=Spirits&top_category=25208&sortBy=0&searchSource=E&pageView=&beginIndex=0#facet:&productBeginIndex:0&orderBy:&pageView:&minPrice:&maxPrice:&pageSize:&

However, I can't seem to access the item information. The information I'm after is the name and link for each product, which for example for the first item is contained in:

`<a class="catalog_item_name" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" id="WC_CatalogEntryDBThumbnailDisplayJSPF_3074457345616901168_link_9b" href="/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10051&amp;storeId=10051&amp;productId=3074457345616901168&amp;langId=-1&amp;partNumber=000086630prod&amp;errorViewName=ProductDisplayErrorView&amp;categoryId=1351370&amp;top_category=25208&amp;parent_category_rn=25208&amp;urlLangId=&amp;variety=New+Spirits&amp;categoryType=Spirits&amp;fromURL=%2fwebapp%2fwcs%2fstores%2fservlet%2fCatalogSearchResultView%3fstoreId%3d10051%26catalogId%3d10051%26langId%3d-1%26categoryId%3d1351370%26variety%3dNew%2bSpirits%26categoryType%3dSpirits%26top_category%3d25208%26parent_category_rn%3d%26sortBy%3d0%26searchSource%3dE%26pageView%3d%26beginIndex%3d0">Woodford Reserve Master Collection Five Malt Stouted Mash</a>`

So the information I'm trying to scrape is:

`Woodford Reserve Master Collection Five Malt Stouted Mash`

and

`/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10051&amp;storeId=10051&amp;productId=3074457345616901168&amp;langId=-1&amp;partNumber=000086630prod&amp;errorViewName=ProductDisplayErrorView&amp;categoryId=1351370&amp;top_category=25208&amp;parent_category_rn=25208&amp;urlLangId=&amp;variety=New+Spirits&amp;categoryType=Spirits&amp;fromURL=%2fwebapp%2fwcs%2fstores%2fservlet%2fCatalogSearchResultView%3fstoreId%3d10051%26catalogId%3d10051%26langId%3d-1%26categoryId%3d1351370%26variety%3dNew%2bSpirits%26categoryType%3dSpirits%26top_category%3d25208%26parent_category_rn%3d%26sortBy%3d0%26searchSource%3dE%26pageView%3d%26beginIndex%3d0`

I'm trying to iterate this for every item on the page. I'm definitely connecting to the page, yet for some reason I can't scrape any information using `for product in soup.select` Below is a simplified version of my script in which I've been trying to gather information from the above catalog_item_name

```
import requests
import sys
import time
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import hashlib
from urllib.request import urlopen
from datetime import datetime
import json
import random
import requests
from itertools import cycle
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()


user_agent_list = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
]
for i in range(1,4):
    #Pick a random user agent
    user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)



url = []
url = 'https://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CatalogSearchResultView?storeId=10051&catalogId=10051&langId=-1&categoryId=1351370&variety=New+Spirits&categoryType=Spirits&top_category=25208&sortBy=0&searchSource=E&pageView=&beginIndex=0#facet:&productBeginIndex:0&orderBy:&pageView:&minPrice:&maxPrice:&pageSize:&'

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,features="html.parser")
link = []

for product in soup.select('a.catalog_item_name'):
    link.append(product)

print(link)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Tested the script with two other websites and it works just fine. There must be something about the site which is throwing it off?

Comment: Maybe it does not work because of missing cookies? Your bs4 logic seems to be working (in theory).

Comment: @js-on could you expand? It certainly works fine for other pages, so it must be the page in question that's causing the issues. How could I add cookies in this case?

Comment: I suggest you `print(soup)` to see what is actually being returned. You might need to use selenium rather than requests

Comment: Why would they use selenium instead of just querying the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the best approach here is to inspect the network traffic and query the API directly. Eg for above url there is some `POST` request against an API at `https://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryProductsListingView`.

I can use that to get a list of products, ie:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib

base_url = 'https://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com'
path = '/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryProductsListingView?sType=SimpleSearch&resultsPerPage=15&sortBy=0&disableProductCompare=false&ajaxStoreImageDir=%2fwcsstore%2fWineandSpirits%2f&variety=New+Spirits&categoryType=Spirits&ddkey=ProductListingView'
params = {
    'storeId': '10051',
    'categoryId': '1351370',
    'searchType': '1002'
}

headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'some super fancy browser',
}

request_url = base_url + path + '&' + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
response = requests.post(request_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

# now, extract the content form the soup, eg like you did above
product_links: list[str] = [base_url + a['href'] for a in soup.select('a.catalog_item_name')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is unfortunately producing the following error for me:

```product_links: list[str] = [base_url + a['href'] for a in soup.select('a.catalog_item_name')]
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were using a recent Python version. Use the pre-3.9 syntax for type hints then (import List and use List[str]) or just remove them completely (ie simply assigning the value to the variable `product_links`)

Comment: Is there a way that I can scrape just the title using my style of code? E.g. Woodford Reserve Master Collection Five Malt Stouted Mash for the first item? I'm trying the following but I can't seem to get the data:

```for product in soup.select('a.catalog_item_name'):
    link.append(product['a.href'])```

Comment: ```link.append(product.a['href'])``` is also not working unfortunately

Comment: The BeautifulSoup objects you get with `soup.select('a.catalog_item_name')` are an anchor elements. Then, `product.a` will give you a child of type `a`. `product['href']`, conversely, will give you a property of the current BeautifulSoup object. The description, again, is not nested in another anchor element but the text between the opening and closing anchor tags. In your case, you can simply select `product.text`. In other cases you might have to select `product.next_element` (which will not return a `str` but a `NavigableString`, which is BeautifulSoup's way of saying: this is a text)